# How to obtain authorization token for skype bot apis?

Tags: api, oauth, skype, botframework, skype-bots

I want to create a skype bot and am referring to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots/docs/api/chat , for authorization the doc refers to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code/ but it is unclear about the scope to be mentioned for using skype bot apis.

So can anybody tell me how to obtain authorization token for making skype bot rest api calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'client_id=<your-app-id>&client_secret=<your-app-secret>&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default' 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

Comment: Woohoo! Thank you so much for sharing this. It is not at all clear from their docs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to try token access to the skype bot.
I have also tried the above mentioned cURL function in "POSTMAN" but I have this return message:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: 53dcaec0-...\r\nCorrelation ID: d6d650ec...\r\nTimestamp: 2018-01-15 09:53:04Z",
    "error_codes": [
        90014
    ],
    "timestamp": "2018-01-15 09:53:04Z",
    "trace_id": "53dcaec0-...",
    "correlation_id": "d6d650ec-..."
}
```

The following is a header and body structure in POSTMAN:

**HEADER**
Content_type: application/x-www-url-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache

**BODY**
client_id=&client_secret=&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default

In **BODY** I replace the fields *client_id* and *client_secret* with the correct codes provided during registration.
Thanks to the availability...

Comment: Your "Answer" looks like a question. Please only post answers to the problem as an answer.